# Quick sort parameters

Tags: c++, quicksort

I'm trying to apply a quicksort snippet to my program; however, none of the vast amount of tutorials or examples that I've found explain in layman's terms what I use for the second and third parameters, most commonly referred to as left and right; the explainations are not in simple enough terms for me to understand.

Beneath is the snippet verbatim; if there are any issues I apologize.

```
void quickSort(int arr[], int left, int right) 
{
    int i = left, j = right;
    int tmp;
    int pivot = arr[(left + right) / 2];
      /* partition */
    while (i <= j) 
    {
        while (arr[i] < pivot)
            i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
            j--;
        if (i <= j)
        {
            tmp = arr[i];
            arr[i] = arr[j];
            arr[j] = tmp;
            i++;
            j--;
        }
    };

      /* recursion */
    if (left < j)
    quickSort(arr, left, j);

    if (i < right)
    quickSort(arr, i, right);
}
```

I understand that the first parameter is the array to be sorted, but what exactly in reference to that array am I passing in for "left" and "right?"

I've been coding for a few years now but I haven't had the best guidance, so if this is remedial to you please educate me as I'm still very much in the learning phase.

Comment: This does not appear to be a correct implementation of quicksort. First issue is that your indentation does not match the code. Fix the indentation.

Comment: The code sorts some random arrays that I tested it with, so it appears to be a correct implementation.

Comment: Basically, it chooses a pivot element in the middle of the array, and puts all elements less than the pivot to the left of the pivot and all elements greater than the pivot to the right of it.  I then calls quick sort on the array to the left of the pivot, and quick sort on the array including and to the right of the pivot.

Comment: Right, it's just the formatting that is confusing.

Comment: The indentation of the two single-line while loops which increment and decrement `i` and `j` respectively, is wrong.  `i` is incremented until the the element at location `i` is greater than the pivot, and `j` is decremented until the location at `j` is less than the pivot.

Comment: I apologize for the formatting, but didn't want to potentially complicate the issue by tampering with the format of the original snippet too much. I'm new so I don't know if it pollutes the Q/A aspect if I edit the snippet at this point to correct your concerns? The sort IS working after implementation but I will clean it up for future readability sake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `left` and `right` are indexes into the array to be sorted for the current invocation of the quicksort call.

When you first call quicksort at the top level, `left` and `right` are the complete array. For example:

```
int arr[] = { 3,4,6,2,5,6,6,7,4,4,6,5,3,6,7,8,8,6,4,3 };

quicksort(arr, 0, 19);
```

Comment: Thank you, this has been a great explanation.  None of the explanations I had found disambiguated those two parameters with clarity you just did.

Answer (score 0):

Before I answer there is one point,

```
while (i <= j) 
{
    while (arr[i] < pivot)
        i++;
        while (arr[j] > pivot)
            j--;
            if (i <= j) 
            {
                tmp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = tmp;
                i++;
                j--;
            }
};
```

This part of your code has a while loop that is indented incorrectly, so it is a bit confusing.

So the left and the right are referring the left and right most index of your desired array.

Let's say that we have an array

`[1, 4, 5, 6, 3]`

the sorting part of quick sort will arrange the array into 

`[1, 4, 3, 6, 5]`

What happens after is a you will have the recursive call to 

`quickSort(arr, 0, 2)
quickSort(arr, 3, 4)`

So one quickSort will sort them based on the left (index 0) to right (index 2) and another will quickSort base on the left (index 3) to the right (index 4) until the array has reach the length < 1